# My material for my donut bun is glowing

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor

[image]

I finished my donut texturing and and don't know why its glowing. I'm pretty sure it wasn't there from when I started to add texture to the donut. I don't know how to make it stop glowing

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+LMB click on the principled shader...

Comment: Actually, this looks pretty cool IMO

Comment: radioactive donut. Give Homer Simpson a call, he'd enjoy it.

Comment: Saw your doughnut and thought... Blender Guru is awesome. By the way, so are you for jumping into blender

Answer (score 9):

The viewer node you are using is actually an Emission Shader. To stop the glowing, plug the Principled BSDF into the Material Output.